# Can't use fixup_bundle() to create a portable bundle with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I already searched this issue on other posts, but nothing so far. So here I am.

I'd like to create a bundle that is portable. Portable as in "I can run it on any OS X machine, even if my required libs (Qt) are not installed". Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use fixup_bundle() (which seems the right tool for it) to achieve this goal.

Here is my minimal CMake generated C++ project :

main.cpp

```c
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
    QString s("Hello, world!");
    std::cout << s.toStdString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(test)

# That part because I use a custom build of Qt. That's not the
# relevant part (I guess?)
FILE(GLOB QTROOTS path_to_qt/Qt-4.8.1/osx/bin/qmake)
find_program(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE NAMES qmake PATHS ${QTROOTS})
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_executable(test MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test ${QT_LIBRARIES})

install(SCRIPT bundle.cmake)
```

bundle.cmake

```
INCLUDE(BundleUtilities)
fixup_bundle(test.app "" "")
```

Here's the resulting test.app structure

```
test.app
 - Contents
    - Info.plist
    - Frameworks
       - QtCore.framework
          - Versions
             - 4
                - QtCore
    - MacOS
       - test
```

Everything that is needed seems to be in the bundle. Everything compiles smoothly, runs well, but when I invoke fixup_bundle, that's what I get :

```
vincent@hpcd0016-lion:tmp/test_bundle/ (0) > make install

[100%] Built target test
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- fixup_bundle
--   app='test.app'
--   libs=''
--   dirs=''
-- fixup_bundle: preparing...
-- fixup_bundle: copying...
-- 1/4: *NOT* copying '/Users/vincent/tmp/test_bundle/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test'
-- 2/4: copying 'path_to_qt/Qt-4.8.1/osx/lib//QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore'
-- fixup_bundle: fixing...
-- 3/4: fixing up '/Users/vincent/tmp/test_bundle/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test'
  exe_dotapp_dir/='test.app/Contents/MacOS/'
  item_substring='/Users/vincent/t'
  resolved_embedded_item='/Users/vincent/tmp/test_bundle/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test'

Install or copy the item into the bundle before calling fixup_bundle.
Or maybe there's a typo or incorrect path in one of the args to fixup_bundle?

CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:568 (message):
  cannot fixup an item that is not in the bundle...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake 2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:656 (fixup_bundle_item)
  bundle.cmake:2 (fixup_bundle)
  cmake_install.cmake:31 (INCLUDE)


make: *** [install] Error 1
```

There's the dependencies path (given by otool -L) :

```
vincent@hpcd0016-lion:test.app/Contents/ (0) > otool -L test.app/Contents/MacOS/test     
    test.app/Contents/MacOS/test:
        path_to_qt/Qt-4.8.1/osx/lib//QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
        /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)

vincent@hpcd0016-lion:tmp/test_bundle/ (0) > otool -L test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
    test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore:
        path_to_qt/Qt-4.8.1/osx/lib//QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 41.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.15.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55010.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1094.0.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 53.0.0)
```

Obviously, fixup_bundle did not fix up the bundle for the binaries still have their ids set to my machine's paths.

What am I doing wrong on this simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added this line at the top of my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

And that was it.

By default, apparently, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set to /usr/local on my machine. If changing it to my current working directory solved the issue, that means CMake was trying to perform some operations on /usr/local (which it is not allowed to do). So why the error message does not mention such a right access error?

I don't know if I haven't read enough documentation, or if the documentation needs some precisions...

Comment: The documentation needs some precisions... I have been fighting exactly the same issue recently. Made me waste some hours.

Comment: I have the same issue, and setting install prefix to some writeable desktop dir unfortunately seems not enough.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I actually had to be even more explicit about the install path (i.e. within the .app).

Like this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
install(CODE "
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/MyApp.app \"\" \"\")
" COMPONENT Runtime)
```

(N.B. no separate SCRIPT but rather embedded CODE - shouldn't make a difference).

Comment: How did you solve the problem that qt platform plugin (libqcocoa.dylib) is not bundled with the rest?

Answer (score 2):

To respond to timlukins' answer, if you're going to invoke any CMake variables in the *install* code then you have to be very careful to escape them against early evaluation.

The code you posted will resolve `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` immediately, before it embeds your code into the install script. Which means the `cmake_install.cmake` file will contain:

```
include(BundleUtilities)
fixup_bundle(/usr/local/MyApp.app "" "")
```

(Or whatever path you had `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set to when generating the build tree.) That's not what you want, since it makes your build unrelocatable even **before** it's installed.

You need to protect the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` invocation so it makes it into the install script intact, and will use the install-time value. There's two ways you can do that.

1. Furious escaping within the quotes...

   ```
   install(CODE "
     include(BundleUtilities)
     fixup_bundle(\"\$\{CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX\}/MyApp.app\" \"\" \"\")
   " COMPONENT Runtime)
   ```
2. (Much easier:) Use a [*bracket argument*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html?highlight=bracket#id19)...

   ```
   install(CODE [[
     include(BundleUtilities)
     fixup_bundle("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/MyApp.app" "" "")
   ]] COMPONENT Runtime)
   ```

No variable names will be recognized or references replaced inside a bracket argument, so it's safe to use them unescaped. (Generator expressions *will* still be processed, which can sometimes be quite handy. Not for this, exactly, but I did just think of one way...)

To oarfish's comment question:

> How did you solve the problem that qt platform plugin (libqcocoa.dylib) is not bundled with the rest?

Here's how I might handle that. It's lightly tested, seems to at least be on the right track. Though I can't help feeling like there must be an easier way to handle the output paths.

```
install(CODE [[
  include(BundleUtilities)

  # You could also do this part before the CODE using
  #   install(TARGETS MyApp BUNDLE DESTINATION foo)
  #
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/foo"
    TYPE DIRECTORY FILES "$<TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR:MyApp>")

  # This string is crazy-long enough that it's worth folding into a var...
  set (_plugin_file "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:Qt5::QCocoaIntegrationPlugin>")

  # Ditto the output paths for our installation
  set (_appdir "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/foo/MyApp.app")
  set (_outdir "${_appdir}/Contents/plugins/platforms")

  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${_outdir}"
    TYPE FILE FILES "$<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::QCocoaIntegrationPlugin>")

  fixup_bundle("${_appdir}" "${_outdir}/${_plugin_file}" "")
]] COMPONENT Runtime)
```

As soon as you generate the build system, you can read the `cmake_install.cmake` file that's output into the binary directory for this `CMakeLists.txt` file, to see if the `install(CODE...)` produced what you intended.

#### Destination path

If you're wondering where that `${_outdir}` path came from, that's Word of God.

From Qt's "[Using `qt.conf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html#overriding-paths)":

> Absolute paths are used as specified in the `qt.conf` file. All paths are relative to the `Prefix`. [...] On macOS, the `Prefix` is relative to the `Contents` in the application bundle. For example, `application.app/Contents/plugins/` is the default location for loading Qt plugins. Note that the plugins need to be placed in specific sub-directories under the `plugins` directory (see [How to Create Qt Plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) for details).